# Minifying both original and RTL CSS with Gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I need to output minified version of both the original CSS and the generated RTL version using Gulp. However, since these CSS are originally compiled from SASS, I also want to keep the sourcemaps if possible.

Here is the task using `gulp-rtlcss` before minification:

```
gulp.task("sass", function() {
    return gulp.src("scss/style.scss")
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        // sass and autoprefixer here
        .pipe(gulp.dest("css"))
        .pipe(rtlcss())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: "-rtl" }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("css"))
});
```

These codes output:

```
style.css
style-rtl.css
```

What I want to achieve is to output the minified version of both,

```
style.min.css
style-rtl.min.css
```

which I doubt this can be done in only one stream. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done in a single stream.

First I don't understand this about your code-block:
I don't know how you have set up your `rtlcss()` variable. I believe rtlcss is used only convert ltr styles to rtl. For minifying the stylesheets you can use `minifyCSS    = require('gulp-clean-css');`. An then add `.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))` in your pipeline.

Extra information:

**Some times you may also want to include/exclude the rtl files from you pipe stream**
I have used gulp package `gulp-filter` to work together with the RTL or LTR(regular) stylesheets in a single stream.
You will first define a filter like the following
`const filterRTL = filter(["**/*.css", "**/!*-rtl.css"], {restore: true});`

The filterRTL will remove all the RTL files in the stream and you can work with your LTR styles the way you want.

```
gulp.task('minify', function(){
    gulp.src([unminified + "**/*.css", unminified + "*.css"])
    // .pipe(filterRTL)
    // .pipe(filterRTL2)
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(rename(function(opt) {
        opt.basename = opt.basename.replace("-rtl.min", ".min-rtl");
        return opt;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(minified));
});
```

In the above snippet I was first testing the minification without the RTL files and then I commented the filters out.

**You can also rename in any way you want:**
Please note the inline rename function in the code block. This will rename `mystyle-rtl.min.css` to `mystyle.min-rtl.css`. I know the naming convention is that great, but I didn't choose it. :)